# How to run a function for more ID's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable the previous button in a form, when the user checked some options. So if he select for ID 1 OR 2 OR 3 the previous button must be disabled.

But if the user checked for 1 and not for 2 OR 3, the previous button must stay disabled. If he doesn't select for 1 OR 2 OR 3, the previous button must be enabled.

I tried the following:

```js
$.each(["1", "2", "3"], function(index, mainOption) {
  $('#option_' + mainOption).change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('#previous_button').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#previous_button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="checkbox">
  <li class="option_1">
    <input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="option1" id="option_1">
    <label>Option 1</label>
  </li>
  <li class="option_2">
    <input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="option2" id="option_2">
    <label>Option 2</label>
  </li>
  <li class="option_3">
    <input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="option3" id="option_3">
    <label>Option 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="previous_button" class="previous_button button" value="Back">
```

Associated [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fo5c1dmj/6/)

So you see that unchecking one of them enable the button

I tried, but this doesn't do exactly what I want, using this the button will be enabled when 1 OR 2  OR 3 is checked and unchecking one of them will enable the button. That's not what I want. If one of the options are checked, the previous button must stay disabled. Only if one of them are not checked, the button must be enabled.

Comment: why not use a class and run function on that?

Comment: because the options has not specific class, only specific IDs @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: so you can edit the JS but not the html?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes, it's a plugin for a CMS.

Comment: Can you create an example here: jsfiddle.net and paste the link?

Comment: @Jackowski It's better to use the snippet feature in the question text editor so that code is hosted here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jackowski https://jsfiddle.net/fo5c1dmj/6/ So you see unchecking one of the options enable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider all checkboxes (this code can still be optimized):

```
let ids = ["1", "2", "3"];
$.each(ids, function( index, mainOption ) {
    $('#option_'+mainOption).change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $('#previous_button').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            let cnt = 0;
            $.each(ids, function( index, mainOption ) {
                if ($('#option_'+mainOption).prop('checked')) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            })
            if (cnt === 0) {
                $('#previous_button').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work.. unchecking other option enable the button.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I fixed the answer. The check should be `if ($('#option_'+mainOption).prop('checked')) {
`

Comment: this works! thanks. just checking if I understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [event delegation mechanism](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and register your listener on the first common ancestor and apply `disabled` property to the *previous* button whether one or more checkboxes have been checked or not.

```js
// The function used to filter eligible checkboxes
// to be passed to jQuery "filter" function below
let myFilter = function (i, el) {
  // Only include checkboxes whose id matches the following pattern
  return /-[12]$/.test(el.id)
}

// Register click event on the first common ancestor
$('form').on('click', function(e) {
  let $form = $(this), $target = $(e.target);

  // If a checkbox get clicked
  if ($target.is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    let shouldDisable = !!$form.find('input:checked').filter(myFilter).length;
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', shouldDisable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h2>Select one or more items</h2>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox" />
  <br />
  <button type="button">Prev</button>
</form>
```

Which applied to your markup gives:

```js
let myFilter = function(i, el) {
  return /_[12]$/.test(el.id)
}
$('ul').on('click', function(e) {
  let $ul = $(this),
    $target = $(e.target);

  if ($target.is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    let shouldDisable = !!$ul.find('input:checked').filter(myFilter).length;
    $ul.next().prop('disabled', shouldDisable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li class="option_1">
    <input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="option1" id="option_1">
    <label>Option 1</label>
  </li>
  <li class="option_2">
    <input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="option2" id="option_2">
    <label>Option 2</label>
  </li>
  <li class="option_3">
    <input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="option3" id="option_3">
    <label>Option 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="previous_button" class="previous_button button" value="Back">
```

Comment: this is what I want, but how can I just select self the options. I just only want for example option 1 and 2 @Stphane

Comment: You might achieve this simply by building a valid _sizzle_ _(the library used by jQuery to parse selectors)_ selector with the values you need. I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: hmm, don't understand how that works. Can you maybe update the answer within my situation on https://jsfiddle.net/fo5c1dmj/6/

Comment: @can, what do you mean when you say `"but how can I just select self the options"`?

Comment: @Joonas I mean if I want to disable the button for each choice/ checkbox.

Comment: @can  I have updated the answer. As you can see, now only checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 state will command previous button disabled property. I also added a snippet using your markup. Please consider setting your question as solved by ticking the answer which helped you the most.

Comment: @Stphane thanks, this one works but is for me a little bit difficult to understand.